# Simple C# Linq to Entities Query does not work

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql

I keep getting an error with the code below. It says `Error "Operator '==' cannot be applied to operands of type 'string' and 'int'.` I have watched a video and Julie Lerman does the exact same thing. She doesn't get the error though. Why?

```
private static void CustomerQuery()
{
    var context = new NorthwindEntities();
    var query = from c in context.Customers
                where c.CustomerID == 5
                select c;

    var customers = query.FirstOrDefault();
}
```

Comment: Because CustomerID is string (varchar) in your DB table?

Comment: Are you sure that Customer.CustomerID is an int and not a string?

Comment: Is CustomerID an integer? If not then of course this won't work, the error tells you the problem, you can't perform a direct comparison on a string and an integer.

Comment: The simple answer is that your c.CustomerId is not an int. What is in the NorthwindEntries context class? How is it defined there? How is it defined on your db?

Comment: Interesting that you say there is an example where this work. Have you got a link to that. Is Julie using exactly the same database or just a similar example?

Comment: It was the same database. One if the AW databases. The CustomerID was a string, I never thought to check that and just assumed it was an int data type.

Answer (score 1):

Check the data type of CustomerID. Else convert them to int.

Answer (score 1):

thats it,check the type of customer id in table ,if it is string change the query to

```
private static void CustomerQuery()

       {
            var context = new NorthwindEntities();
            var query = from c in context.Customers
                        where c.CustomerID == "5"  
                        select c;

            var customers = query.FirstOrDefault();
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

try with `where c.CustomerID == "5"` instead.

Comment: it's doublequotes for string in c#

Comment: Should this not be `where c.CustomerID == "5"?` i.e double quotes rather than single.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that `CustomerID` is not of type `int`. `Typecast` it to `int` to compare it with an `int datatype`.